# How to connect to docker host?

Tags: docker

I'm a bit confused about "what" a docker host is and how is it different from my system in itself.

I did the following,

```
docker run jenkins

/* in a new tab */
docker ps // to get the container id
docker inspect {container-id} // to get the IP
```

From what I understand the only way I can connect to the container's IP is from within the `docker host` (if I don't port map that is) - so how do I connect to the host?

I know I can `bash` into the container and `curl` the IP I got from `inspect`, but that's not the same as connecting to the `docker host`, is it?

Comment: “Docker host” isn’t really a standard term.  You should probably never run that `docker inspect` command; the IP addresses it gives back aren’t stable and aren’t usable in many common circumstances.  You need a `docker run -p` option to make the Jenkins container accessible.

Comment: @DavidMaze Thanks for the explanation! I was actually following a Udemy course; wherein they basically run firefox inside a virtualbox - which is connected to the "host" - and hit the IP returned from `inspect` to show the use of that IP. Couldn't/Still-can't wrap my head around that bit.

Comment: As mentioned here use port mapping to run Jenkins add to docker run command `-p 8080:8080` and you should be able to access Jenkins from your browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you are using the term "docker host" here makes it sound like you are using the term to refer to the container itself.  (You might also be referring to the physical machine which the container is running on).

You can think of the container as basically a very lightweight VM -- it has its own filesystem, network, possibly CPU and RAM resources, etc.  So, without configuring the network, the container will be isolated.  This analogy isn't perfect for any number of reasons, but its pretty close to what is going on.

Put another way, without [port mapping](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/#publish-or-expose-port--p---expose) (or "host networking", see [this page](https://docs.docker.com/network/) for more details about docker networking), you can, as you discovered, only access the network within the container unless you map the ports (or, perhaps, are inside of a different container which is connected to the same [bridge network](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/)).

In this case, you are probably just best off mapping the port so that you can access the service running inside the container.